# hmailserver 550 invalid address error sending via php form

Tags: php, smtp

I have been getting this error endlessly for 2 days. dispite following all proper protocall. The error suggests that the email is invalid yet I use it with squirrel mail with no problems and it appears exactly the same in php.ini I am simply stumped the only thing that makes sense to me is that it is some kind of syntax error somewhere but I can figure out what it would be when I echo $header it displays "From: admin@daysshared.local" is that correct, does it think that the from is part of the email address. I am on the cusp of giving up all together so please help me if you can. Thanks. heres the PHP:

```
$subject = "Your New Password";
$headers = "FROM: admin@dayshare.local";
$message = "Your new password is as follows:

----------------------------
Password:$emailpassword
----------------------------

This email was automatically generated.";

      if (!mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers)){
         echo ("error");
      }else{
            echo"password sent";
```

and in php.ini:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = admin@dayshare.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but just stumbled across it. You have probably fixed it as well by now... 
You mention

displays "From: admin@daysshared.local"

but your header is

$headers = "FROM: admin@dayshare.local";

which are different daysshared.local  & dayshare.local